# add push notification on an already exist app

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I have a first version of an app on the store. For my second version of this app, i want to enable push notifications.

I see that i have to activate push on the appID in the provisioning portal, and then regenerate the provisioning profile of my app.

Is regenerate means juste delete the first one and make another? do this could have effect on the validation process (problem with the difference on the provisioning profile in first version and the one for second version)?

Comment: Go through this link http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Comment: thanks, but i want to know if i modifying my first provisioning profil could have effect on validation of the new version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by changing the settings of your app to use push you need to regenerate the profile so a new one will be created. This is not a problem: if you profile expires you have to generate a new one anyway. The appstore submission process doesn't check the profile against your previously uploaded binary.